# Truck wobbles from 55-60 mph. But steering wheel doesn't shake, changed tires n had rebalanced but still wobbles

Tags: ford, vibration, explorer, wheel-balance

My 2005 Ford Explorer Sport Trac wobbles from 55-60 mph, I changed all four tires and it felt slightly worse, they balanced the tires but I went to kost and they rebalanced the front tires and charged me 40 bucks, said that was the problem but it still wobbles but steering wheel does not wobble at all

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Sounds like this could be Wheel beerings.
If your steering wheel isn't wobbling it means that the wobbling isn't being transfered through the steering rack.

I expect something like wheel beerings, or some other component going bad and causing slop.

Jack the car up and see if there is any side to side and top to bottom play in the wheel. If you jiggle the wheel it shouldnt rock back and forth without turning the steering wheel.

Comment: Were your ball joints checked? They could be loose. And is this a front-wheel or rear-wheel drive truck?

Comment: Bent rim, possibly from hitting a curb.

Comment: You can test wheel balance issues by rotating the fronts to the back. If the shake continues, but it's different, you know it's wheel balance.

Answer (score 0):

Bad wheel bearings. Common issue with Explorers. https://repairpal.com/bearings-boots-wheel-assembly-studs-956

If you want to be sure before taking it into the mechanic, just jack it up enough to get the tire off the ground (E-Brake on), then try to wiggle the tire back and fourth. Tires should be solid with no movement. If there is some free play, then you know it's a bearing.

Just Google "bad wheel bearing" for more information.

Comment: Specifically, grip the top and bottom and wiggle them. Having a slight amount of side to side movement is expected, because the steering isn't fixed.

Comment: Shouldn't there be noise before shaking when it's a bearing? Also, movement slop while jacked up can also be caused by tie rods and ball joints. Each has different give points.